# Why does hot air sink in the eye of a tropical cyclone?

Tags: meteorology, tropical-cyclone, storms

We know that warm air rises in the atmosphere due to the reduced density of the parcel itself. But in the eye of a tropical cyclone the warm air sinks down and does not reach the surface, but gets carried away by strong updrafts. Why do we find this sinking warm and dry air sinking in the eye of a tropical cyclone?

Comment: What makes you think warm air sinks in the eye of a tropical cyclone? A diagram in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_(cyclone)) suggests otherwise...

Comment: @spencer: He's right (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_(cyclone)#/media/File:Hurricane-profile-en.svg in that article).  Arun, the central answer revolves around it warms BECAUSE it is forced to sink.  Will try to piece together a good answer if no one else beats me to it :)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Go ahead, I'd love to see a comprehensible answer to that. In the wiki article it is mentioned that "From hydrostatic balance, the warm core translates to lower pressure at the center at all altitudes, with the maximum pressure drop located at the surface." which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Spencer maybe a change in pressure?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape combination of two balances - gradient /cyclostrophic balance and hydrostatic balance. Then the scale. Over the period over which a cyclone intensifies hydrostatic balance is more applicable than nonhydrostatic waves.